# Some packages are not compatible with .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, asp.net-core, azure-devops, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET Core application that compiles and runs locally. When I try to restore the nuget packages on Visual Studio Team Services (hosted agent) the following errors occurs:

> Ix-Async 1.2.5 is not compatible with .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4.
>
> Remotion.Linq 2.0.1 is not compatible with .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4.
>
> System.Collections.Immutable 1.1.36 is not compatible with
>   .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4.
>
> Some packages are not compatible with .NETPlatform,Version=v5.4.
>
> Ix-Async 1.2.5 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
>
> Remotion.Linq 2.0.1 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
>
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible
>   with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
>
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible
>   with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
>
> Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
>
> System.Exception: Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeToolCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
>   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

The VSTS task that is failing is configured like this:

[image: Nuget restore task]

global.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}
```

And the project.json file from the web project:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "4.2.1",
    "Cubic.Site.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "Cubic.Site.Data.Storage": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
    "StyleCop.Error.MSBuild": "1.0.0",
    "StyleCop.MSBuild": "4.7.54"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "dependencies": {
        }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

The solution contains the web app and 2 other class libraries. Site.Data project.son file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Site.Data Class Library",
  "authors": [ "foo" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the other class library project.json file content is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Site.Data.Storage Class Library",
  "authors": [ "foo" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": ""
      }
    },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Cubic.Site.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
}
```

Any idea on what's going on? The strange thing is that the first time this error occurred there were absolutely no changes to config files, project files or the solution - only ASP.NET MVC views were modified. Since that moment I wasn't able to restore the nuget packages on VSTS.

I was wondering if something was installed on the hosted agent that is causing this error?

***EDIT 2016-06-21***

This issue is now fixed, these errors no longer occur!!! I suspect that there were some changes on the hosted agent that would fix this issue, maybe someone from the VSTS can confirm that??

Comment: Do you have any machinewide nuget feeds that are configured on your local machine but not on the build machone or project-wide nuget.config? On a side note, you should migrate to RC2 and dotnet-cli, DNX is not maintained anymore and deprecated

Comment: Thanks @Tseng, I do have a `nuget.config` in the solution folder that I use to restore the packages on VSTS. Regarding DNX I will pass that information to the developers, it's up to them to migrate or not.

Comment: Can you try using "dnu restore" to restore the packages?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I am using the `Prebuild.ps1` script from [https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/aspnet-core10-azure-web-apps#code](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/aspnet-core10-azure-web-apps#code). This will run `dnu restore` on all `project.json` files in the `src` folder

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I added a screenshot of the VSTS task that is failing (Nuget Restore).

Comment: So you have packages not included in the project.json file?

Comment: Yes, there are some class libraries that don't have the project.json file, e.g. unit test projects that contain packages such as NUnit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't see this issue anymore, it should be caused by the nuget version in Hosted Build Agent. Refer to this link for details: [Issues with Hosted Build in Visual Studio Team Services – 6/20 – Resolved](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/06/21/issues-with-hosted-build-in-visual-studio-team-services-620-investigating/).

> Final Update: Tuesday, 21 June 2016 16:07 UTC
>
> Our hotfix deployment to restore nuget 3.3 on the Build Agents has
>   completed by 21 June 2016 ~03:00 UTC. Customers should no longer see
>   any issues with running Hosted Builds due to nuget package restore.
>
> We understand that customers rely on VS Team Services as a critical
>   service and apologize for any impact this incident caused.
>
> Sincerely, Manohar
>
> Update: Monday, 20 June 2016 22:10 UTC
>
> The update to nuget.exe from 3.3 to 3.4.3 has been identified as the
>   root cause of the active restore problems.  We are working on a hotfix
>   to restore the previous nuget version on the build agents.
>
> We will update this post as the hotfix progresses.
>
> Sincerely, Sri Harsha
>
> Initial Update: Monday, 20 June 2016 19:40 UTC We are actively
>   investigating issues with the build agents of Visual Studio Team
>   services related to nuget  package restore. Some customers may
>   experience Build failures due to nuget packages being restored
>   incorrectly in the Build Agents.
>
> Next Update: Before 22:00 UTC We are actively working to resolve this
>   issue and apologize for any inconvenience.
>
> Sincerely, Manohar

Comment: Hi Eddie, I don't see how that would help. Packages seem to be installed/restored correctly, the problem is that `Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0`

Comment: Issue disappeard (!!!) - don't ask me how... Changes in the hosted agent??

Comment: @RuiJarimba Then it is caused by the nuget version is hosted build agent which has been fixed now.

Comment: As I suspected. Thanks Eddie

Comment: I will keep an eye on VSTS' Service Blog from now on.